# Operator not found or unexpected

Tags: bash, shell, sh

First I want to apologize for being an absolute noob at programming, writing scripts, etc. I have a question about some code I used to run on my old FreeNAS 11.1 machine. I also created a thread back when I initiated the script. Back then I got the help and my script worked. Now I updated to FreeNAS 11.2 and get some messages and I want to know why they appear and how to fix this.

But first the Background. My script checks if any Client is online (by pinging the IP-address):

```
#!/bin/bash

HOST1=10.10.0.100 #Client 1
HOST2=10.10.0.101 #Client 2 
HOST3=10.10.0.102 #Client 3 
HOST4=10.10.0.103 #Client 4
HOST5=10.10.0.104 #Client 5

_exit () { 
case $1 in 
1) echo „No Shutdown – At least one PC is online“ ;; 
2) echo „No PC is online – Shutdown“ ;; shutdown -p now }

#Check if IPs are online 
if [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST1 | grep -wc 100.0%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST2 | grep -wc 100.0%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST3 | grep -wc 100.0%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST4 | grep -wc 100.0%` -eq 0 ] || [ `ping -c 1 -i 1 $HOST5 | grep -wc 100.0%` -eq 0 ] ; then _exit 1;

#All Clients are offline, shutdown else                                                                                                                                                                                           
_exit 2 fi
```

The script itself works fine. If one client is online the script stops and if all clients are offline the Server shutsdown. But i get the following message when i run it manually via the Shell:

```
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try `grep --help' for more information.
shutdown_check.sh: -wc not found
[: -eq: unexpected operator
```

When I ran it on my old Server (11.1) i did not get this message so it is interesting for my, why it now occurs.

Comment: Run `bash -x yourscript`, and the problem will be obvious.

Comment: ...well, except for the `grep -wc` error; for *that*, you'll want to compare `man grep` between the two machines.

Comment: BTW, consider having a single *array* of hosts, and iterating over the array instead of having a bunch of repeated code.

Comment: ...that said, the `grep` error *causes* the "unexpected operator" error, since `-eq` is only valid when it's between a word on the left and a word on the right, and a `grep` that failed with a usage error emits *no* output and thus, when used unquoted, parses into zero words.

Comment: ...anyhow, you'd be in a much better place if you stopped using `grep` altogether and only checked `ping`'s exit status; you wouldn't even need `[` if you did that.

Comment: You can simplify `if [ \`cmd\` = 0 ] || [ \`cmd\` = 0 ]` to `if cmd || cmd`.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net

Comment: @sergio, that's not a general-purpose simplification -- the former checks *output*; the latter checks *exit status*. Of course, `ping` *does* usefully indicate whether the remote system could be contacted in its exit status (just as `grep` indicates whether any matches were seen in its stdin the same way), so that's not a big change.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  thanks for clarifying the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of separate, independent, unrelated bugs in the above code (making the question "too broad" to be within site rules; this community-wiki answer combines answers from the many flagged duplicates). Consider the below rewrite:

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=(
  10.10.0.100 #Client 1
  10.10.0.101 #Client 2 
  10.10.0.102 #Client 3 
  10.10.0.103 #Client 4
  10.10.0.104 #Client 5
)

for host in "${hosts[@]}"; do
  if ping -c 1 -i 1 "$host" >/dev/null; then
    echo "No Shutdown - At least one PC ($host) is online"
    exit 0
  fi
done

echo "No PC is online - Shutdown"
shutdown -p now
```

---

So, what *specifically* was wrong with the original code?

- When you run `[ $(...something...) -eq 0 ]`, you only get a valid `test` statement if `...something...` emits *exactly one word* as output. When you give `grep` invalid syntax, it doesn't emit *any* output at all, so the result is `[ -eq 0 ]`. Since `[` doesn't recognize `-eq` when not between two separate arguments, you have your error.
- If you quoted correctly, as in `[ "$(...something...)" -eq 0 ]`, then you'd have a more useful error message (akin to the one given to `[ "" -eq 0 ]`.
- Your version of `grep` does not recognize `-wc` as a valid combination of arguments.
- The use of `grep` was itself unnecessary; `ping` reflects success or failure in exit status, so one can directly run `if ping ...; then`.
- The syntax was broken in some other respects as well; running the original code through http://shellcheck.net/ will show them.

Comment: Hey, First Thank you for your comment, i tried the code and it worked flawless and even faster then the other code. Now i want to add a function which also checks if a scrub or a resilver is still in progress. I found a python-code but it won't bring my anything i guess. Any idea how to implement it in bash ?

Comment: Not nearly enough details given in the comment to allow an answer -- I don't even know if you're talking about a btrfs resilver or a ZFS resilver, whether (if it is ZFS) if you're talking about the userspace or kernelspace implementations, etc.

Comment: @AlphaInc. If your question is how to programatically get that information from the ZFS tools, you might ask a question about them at [unix.se]; whereas if you *know* how to get that information from the ZFS tools but don't know how to do the language-level operations in bash to interpret the output, consider asking a new question, showing the command you're running, the output you're receiving from it but don't know how to interpret, and your best-effort attempt at interpreting that output.

Comment: Well i use FreeNAS 11.2 and I'm talking about ZFS resilver (using RAID-Z2). But I will ask the question in Unix & Linux.